# Who is for SegWit and who is against? And what is the consensus?

Tags: segregated-witness

I am a little lost in the whole political landscape of implementing SegWit, I understand that Bitcoin Core is for SegWit but are the miners against it? If not then who is against it and what is their proposal?

I have tried googling to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

SegWit is a large protocol update developed by Bitcoin Core to address some protocol defects, increase the capacity, and lay the groundwork for further protocol improvements in the future. As such, it has [broad support](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Segwit_support) among the Bitcoin Core contributors. It also has broad [support among node operators](http://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin/files/charts/segwit.html) with 85%+ being segwit ready, and [decent support among Bitcoin businesses](https://coin.dance/poli). The softfork was ready for activation since November but had been lacking signalling by miners.
This impasse was broken by a combination of the New York Agreement (NYA) that spawned the segwit2x project and the pressure exerted by BIP148 (the UASF).

There is a vocal minority that proposes scale on-chain primarily. Some of them are opposed to segwit altogether, some want it in a different form as for example a hardfork, some of them just prefer bigger blocks but want segwit later as well. The NYA seems to have been found especially to satisfy their wish for a hardfork to a bigger blocksize, where some parts of the community aren't too keen on the 2x part of that. A small group of them has now decided to preempt the decision by creating Bitcoin Cash today which removed segwit and changed the blocksize to 8MB.